# jQuery scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which makes my content `fadeIn()` when I scroll down. It works perfectly now but if I have to change the content or set my browser on half of the screen, it will not work that good it might even not work at all.

Can anyone give me an idea of how I can make my code more universal ?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
        $("#side-nav").fadeOut();
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 150){
        $("#projects-content").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 420){
        $("#skills-content").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 700){
        $("#contacts-content").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: You are dealing with pixels right now. If you can change it in `%` then it will be universal. For example, `(currentScrolltop/totalHeight)*100`

Comment: well that will solve me the responsive design problem but still I am facing the problem with changing the size of the content

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the top positions of the elements to be faded in you can get their position programmatically using `offset().top`. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $projects = $("#projects-content");
    var $skills = $("#skills-content");
    var $contacts = $("#contacts-content");

    if (scrollTop == 0) {
        $("#side-nav").fadeOut();
    }
    if (scrollTop >= $projects.offset().top) {
        $projects.fadeIn("slow");
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $skills.offset().top) {
        $skills.fadeIn("slow");
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $contacts.offset().top) {
        $contacts.fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: well it works but it's not that effective. If I don't instantly start scrolling down ASAP the user will not see the animation

Comment: In which case add an offset to the `top` value so that the element is marginally visible before being shown, something like `offset.top() + 100`

Answer (score 0):

You:

- should bind as events: 
  `$(window).on('scroll load', function(){...});`
- should use a common class to all elements to fade, e.g use class `toFade`.
- should debounce scroll event

And Finally use e.g:

```
$(function() {
  var $toFade = $('.toFade');
  $(window).on('scroll load', function() {
    clearTimeout(this.fadingTimeout);
    this.fadingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $toFade.not('.faded').filter(function() {
        return $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()
      }).fadeIn().addClass('faded');
    }, 50);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> As suggested in comments, you can calculate the `%` value considering the scrollamount and then apply conditions accordingly.

Try this:

```js
var H = window.innerHeight;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var currVal = (scrollTop / H) * 100;
  console.log(currVal);
  if (currVal == 0) {
    $("#side-nav").fadeOut();
  }
  if (currVal >= 25 && currVal < 50) {
    $("#projects-content").fadeIn("slow");
  }
  if (currVal >= 50 && currVal < 75) {
    $("#skills-content").fadeIn("slow");
  }
  if (currVal >= 75) {
    $("#contacts-content").fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
```

[Fiddle for your reference](https://jsfiddle.net/o9crmjr6/)

`onresize` event is generally not used in many web applications as end-user may not resize his window while using it. If you want to integrate it, use [`window.onresize = funcRef;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)